# Power Bi dasherboard uploaded online connected to excel file does not update

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

from power bi desktop I created a dashboard with links to Saleforce and with a link to an excel table on my computer.
from "edit query" I deactivated the updating of the excel file in the report (it must not update) and I uploaded the dashboard online so that I can share it.
the computer on which I have the excle file does not always stay on, when I go to create a scheduled update of the dashboard, it fails because it cannot connect to the excel file.

my aim is to keep the excel file because I created some measurements (so as not to redo them) and to update the dashboard
you have to update the dashboard with the saleforce dates but not with the excel file

Answer (score 1):

Put the Excel file on SharePoint/Onedrive and import it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Use web connector option in Power BI Desktop option and pase the link for the connected Excel file . It will work fine